# Run a check function before functions in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, promise

I have a fetcher object and before any of the functions of the object run I want to run a token check.  I was wondering if there was a way to run the check initially and then proceed to the get, post, put ..ect.  My fetch object looks like the following:

```
const Fetcher = {
  get: async () => {
    //fetch stuff and return a promise
  },
  post: async () => {
    //fetch stuff and return a promise
  }
  ...ect.
}
```

I would like to do a check of my token for expiration before I fetch any content so something like the following:

```
const checkToken = async () => {
  const exp = Store.getState().auth.tokenExp;

  //check if theres an expiration set
  if (!exp) {
    Store.dispatch({ type: LOGOUT });
    sessionStorage.removeItem('user');
    return false;
  }

  //check if token is not expired
  if (Date.now() < exp * 1000) return true;

  //if token is expired logout and return true
  Store.dispatch({ type: LOGOUT });
  sessionStorage.removeItem('user');
  return false;
};
```

I am starting to do a lot of jumping around here and I am trying to make it more simplistic.  I am using react and redux so I am going from component -> redux action -> fetcher object -> token check already and I was just wondering if there was any easy way to run the check before proceeding to the get, post, put ..ect functions aside from writing another wrapper function.  I can do the check at each of these functions but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Before any fetching? Make your own `fetch` function that wraps original `fetch`, with a `checkToken` prepended.

Comment: @Amadan what do you mean by prepend? And the fetch object is my attempt at making a reusable fetch function so I don't have to keep writing the same fetch code over and over.

Comment: I was assuming you are using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) function in your `Fetcher`. You could just do `function myFetch(...args) { return checkToken().then(() => fetch(...args)) }`, then just use `myFetch` instead of `fetch` everywhere. (You could even locally redefine the identifier `fetch` itself if you wanted to, so almost no code in `Fetcher` would change, though it might be confusing for future maintainers.)

Comment: @Amadan the only issue I have with that is then I have to use that all over my code base.  I was hoping there was a solution where I could tackle the problem at just this one spot instead of littering extra code all over the place.  If I was going to do that I would just put the checks in fetcher object functions.  I'm trying to just make things cleaner.

Comment: I don't understand. This _is_ one spot. If you define a new function like above, you just need to replace `fetch` with `myFetch` in each of the Fetcher functions, with no change to the rest of your code base. If you decide to locally redefine `fetch`, that's five lines of code around your Fetcher object, with no changes to Fetcher object itself, and no change to the rest of your code base. What do you mean by "then I have to use that all over my code base"?

Comment: https://medium.com/netscape/creating-custom-middleware-in-react-redux-961570459ecb - adding middleware might help

Comment: I dont' get why `checkToken` has to be `async` AND return all those promise.resolves/promise.rejects ... just return a value or throw an error inside an `async` ... having said that, why does it even need to be async, whya are you forcing asynchrony on a synchronous function?

Comment: @JaromandaX there isn't that much overhead in using async functions in a standard HTTP application and you can still have a synchronous function body, as long as you use it with `await` or `then` it'll be easier to move to an async implementaion later.

Comment: Sure, @MichałKapracki, unless you need to transpile for IE :p ... but why, in an async function would you `return Promise.resolve(result)` or `Promise.reject(error)` ... just `return result` or `throw error`

Comment: @JaromandaX The checktoken function in the question was a typo.  I just copied it over because the logic was in another function and it really doesn't have anything to do with the actual question I posted and I will edit the question.  That said this entirety of the comments here don't actually address the question I posted.  I wanted to know if there was a way to run one check before any of the fetch requests were run.  I can already run a check at each of the requests there is no reason to write another wrapper for fetch.  I will edit the question to remove the resolving promises.

Comment: @JaromandaX indeed inside an async function there's no need to do that...